# I have to editText side by side how can I make the focus go to the other edittext when there are 2 characters

Tags: android

I need the focus to go to editText2 when the user type 2 numbers in editText1 and vice versa ?

also when I open the app the cursor is in the editText1 while I want it to be in editText2 by default?

hope im making sense

Comment: first tell us what u have done so far ?

Comment: use this <EditText...>
    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

Comment: text watcher is what was missing first comment helped me solve the first problem but im still stuck in the second one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement **addTextChangeListerner**. Try this ,

```
  editText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.toString().length()>=2)
            {
                editText2.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                editText2.requestFocus();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: it's correct for the first problem but i'm still stuck in the second one which when I open the app the focus is on the left editText and I want to be in the right editText

Comment: try this one yourEdittext.requestFocus();

Comment: Then you direct set in xml File.
 <EditText...> <requestFocus /> </EditText>

Comment: I even tried in the xml but for some strange reason is still not working

Comment: It worked when I added android:focusable="false" for the left editText in the xml and I also added setOnTouchListener so when I touch it focusable become true

Answer (score 0):

For the second issue

```
            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:focusable="false"/>

            <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ET2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:inputType="number">
            <requestFocus/>
        </EditText>
```

and in OnCreate:

```
ET1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            v.setFocusable(true);
            v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            return false;
        }
    });
```